# Java program - Counts all the words from a text file, and counts frequency of each word

Tags: java, arrays, text-files

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to do one program that opens a text file with a large text inside and then it counts how many words it contains. 
Then it should write how many different words are in the text, and write the frecuency of each word in the text.
I had the intention to use one array-string to store all unique words and one int-string to store the frequency.

The program counts the words, but I'm a little bit unsure about how could I write the code correctly to get the list of the words and the frequency them are repeated in the text.

I wrote this:

```
import easyIO.*;
import java.util.*;

class Oblig3A{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int cont = 0;
        In read = new In (alice.txt);
        In read2 = new In (alice.txt);

        while(read.endOfFile() == false)
        {
            String info = read.inWord();
            System.out.println(info);
            cont = cont + 1;
        }

        System.out.println(UniqueWords);

        final int AN_WORDS = cont;

        String[] words = new String[AN_WORDS];
        int[] frequency = new int[AN_WORDS];

        int i = 0;
        while(les2.endOfFile() == false){
           word[i] = read2.inWord();
           i = i + 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Start using indentation. Your code will be easier to read this way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is what you need to do:
1. Use a `BufferedReader` to read the lines of text from the file, one by one.
2. Create a `HashMap<String,Integer>` to store the word, frequency relations.
3. When you read each line of text, use `split()` to get all the words in the line of text in an array of `String[]`
4. Iterate over each word. For each word, retrieve the value from the `HashTable`. if you get a null value, you have found the word for the first time. Hence, create a new `Integer` with value 1 and place it back in the `HashMap`
If you get a non-null value, then increment the value and place it back in the `HashMap`.
5. Do this till you do not reach EOF.

Done !

Comment: `HashMap` is correct idea but instead of `BufferedReader` I would use `Scanner` (its `next` and `hasNext` method are simpler). Also OP may be not familiar with Collection framework so pointing methods of `Map` needed to realise this task would be nice.

Comment: There is a frequency() method in java.util.Collections. Could this not also be utilized?

Comment: @EbonyMaw From the docs about `frequency( )` _This method returns the number of elements in the specified collection equal to the specified object._ I doubt :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a

```
Map<String, Integer> map = HashMap<String, Integer>();
```

And then add the words to the map asking if the value is already there. If it is not, add it to the map with a counter initialized to 1.

```
if(!map.containsKey(word))
{
    map.put(word, new Integer("1"));
}
else
{
    map.put(word, map.get(word) + new Integer(1));
}
```

In the end you will have a map with all the words that the file contains and a Integer that represents how many times does the word appear in the text.

Answer (score 0):

You basically need a hash here. In java , you can use a `HashMap<String, Integer>` which will  store words and their frequency.

So when you read in a new word, check it up in the hashMap, say h, and if it exists , increase the frequency or add a new word with frequency = 1.

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a library you may want to consider using a [Guava Multiset](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multiset.html), it has the counting functionality already built in:

```
    public void count() throws IOException {
        Multiset<String> countSet = HashMultiset.create();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("alice.txt"));
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            List<String> words = Arrays.asList(line.split("\\W+"));
            countSet.addAll(words);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        for (Entry<String> entry : countSet.entrySet()) {
          System.out.println("word: " + entry.getElement() + " count: " + entry.getCount());
        }
    }
```